# Can I get the Buffer from fs.createWriteStream()?

Tags: node.js, express, archiverjs, createwritestream

I have simple question - **Can I get the Buffer from fs.createWriteStream()?**

In my case I use **archiver** NPM module which may create archives from Buffer. When this module end work with method **archive.finalize()** I may get result from **archive.pipe(stream)**. I want have **Buffer** from **fs.createWriteStream()** which I may send to **res.send()** Express method.

```
let archive = archiver("zip", {
      zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
    });
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(
      "./src/backend/api/test.zip"
    );
archive.pipe(stream);
archive.append(buffer, { name: "test.csv" });
archive.finalize();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, that might help you

```js
        const stream = fs.createWriteStream(
                "./src/backend/api/test.zip"
            );

        stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            //here u get every chunk as a buffer  
        })
        stream.on('finish', () => {
            //here your code if the stream is ending
        })
```